# Ngx Shell Component is not part of ngModule

Tags: angular, ngxs

I Generated Angular Application using 
https://github.com/ngx-rocket/generator-ngx-rocket

I am getting the below warning when i run the application.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Component ShellComponent is
>   not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your
>   module. Error: Component ShellComponent is not part of any NgModule or
>   the module has not been imported into your module.

i have changed the app-routing file to

```
const routes: Routes = [
  // Shell.childRoutes([
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule' },
    { path: 'about', loadChildren: './about/about.module#AboutModule' },
    { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule' },
    { path: 'signup', loadChildren: './signup/signup.module#SignupModule' },
  // ]),
  // { path: 'login', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
  // Fallback when no prior route is matched
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says:
ShellComponent is not part of any NgModule. Components needs to be part of a Module. The code you pasted in is not relevant to the error you are getting.

I think you should start here:
https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules
Then look at this:
https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components